# Derivative of discrete max operator

Tags: derivatives

I would like to find the derivative of the discrete max operator in numpy. For example, given `a=np.array([1,2,3,2,1])`, calling `np.max(a)` gives `3`. Can this operation be differentiated? From thinking about what the derivative means, it seems that given a small change in `a`, the derivative of `max(a)` should be 0 unless the small change causes `max(a)` to change to a new value, in which case the derivative could be very large indeed. Does this line of thinking make sense at all?
Many thanks!

Comment: $\max(x)$ is not differentiable, but if you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to help.

Comment: Are you differentiating with respect to the array components? The partial derivatives exist almost everywhere, equal to $0$ or $\pm 1$.